# Change href of modal based on button click

Tags: javascript, django

Clicking this button opens the modal

```
<button type="button" id ="soldBtn" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">This laptop has been sold</button>
```

This is the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <p>Confirmation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to do this?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-success" id="confirmBtn" href="#" >Yes</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="cancelBtn" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could just have a different modal for different buttons, but I'd rather follow the DRY principle. I'd like the `href` of the `confirmBtn` to change based on which button to open the modal was clicked. I've tried this so far but not even sure if I'm on the right track.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(jQuery('#soldBtn').data('clicked')) {
    document.getElementById("confirmBtn").href="{%url 'laptops:sale'%}";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first wait for your DOM to load. This can be done by wrapping your script code with the following:

```
$(function(){
    // Here you will place the code that follows
});
```

Then you should register an event handler for the click event on the DOM element with id `soldBtn`:

```
$("#soldBtn").on('click', function(){
    var confirmBtnEle = $("#confirmBtn");
    confirmBtnEle.attr('href','%url 'laptops:sale'%');
});
```

Apparently, you have to change the second argument we pass to `attr` method above to be that you want to be.

Comment: @Christos, I am facing a similar issue with my url pattern, but I am unable to apply it within the attr() method. The url pattern is: '{% url 'delete_file' file.pk %} '.   But it gives syntax error:  confirmBtnEle.attr('href','% url 'delete_file' file.pk %');